# Different types of extension error are showing on vs code after running c program

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have already installed Minigw on my 64-bit windows. I have installed VS code as a code editor.I have done the sample C programme to test the vs code.
After installing the vs code I have installed all`clang extensions` and `intelliSense extension`.

My code is:-

```
   #include <stdio.h>

    int main() {
    int a,b,c;

    printf("enter the no.");

    scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);

    c=a+b;
    printf("%d",c);

    return 0;
}
```

The vs code shows the following errors:-

1)`Error` Please install [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) or check configuration `clang.executable`.

2) #include error detected. Please update your includePath. Intellisense features for this translation unit (c:\user\h\Desktop\codetest.c) will be provided by the tag parser.(1,1)

3) cannot open source file "stdio.h" (1,1)

What are the meaning of this errors?

Comment: Maybe it does not find the includes in the path? have you added LLVM to your path?

Comment: Yes after installing clang I have copied(C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin)- this and add this to the environment variable path.

Comment: The system need to reboot after adding to the environment

Comment: And you have update browse.path settings in your vscode?

Comment: No, plz tell me how to do that.@qwn

Answer (score 0):

Base on this link on [vscode-github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/LanguageServer/MinGW.md) you need to do these steps:

1. Install the basic setup of [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)
2. Modified the c_cpp_properties.json file in your VSCode as given in the GitHub link.